# In a Golang RoundTripper can I read a response Header?

Tags: go, http.client

I'm using Envoy as mTLS proxies on load-balanced servers.
The Go client makes an HTTPS call to the load balancer which responds with a redirect to another server. I need to modify the port number in the response to use the Envoy port.

Is it possible to read `Response.Header.Get("Location")` and create a new response in order to change the port?

The [docs](https://go.dev/src/net/http/client.go) say

> // RoundTrip should not attempt to interpret the response.

It would look like

```
type EnvoyRoundTripper struct {
    PortMapper http.RoundTripper
}

func (ert EnvoyRoundTripper) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (res *http.Response, e error) {
    res, e = ert.PortMapper.RoundTrip(req)

    if e == nil && res.StatusCode == http.StatusTemporaryRedirect {
        redirect := res.Header.Get("Location")
        // res = Create a new Response with a modified redirect
    }

    return
 }
```

Comment: This functionality is better implemented via [Client.CheckRedirect](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect). Remember to limit the number of redirects yourself.